# Not able to compile sass files on Laravel 8 bootstrap

Tags: laravel, dart-sass

When I am trying to compile bootstrap scaffolding on laravel version 8, below errors are coming

```
node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 67:16            row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid-framework.scss 43:13  @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 65:5      media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid-framework.scss 32:5   make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 72:3                    @import
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 16:9                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 8:9                                    root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div(100%, $count)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
66 │     flex: 0 0 100% / $count;
   │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 66:15            row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid-framework.scss 43:13  @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 65:5      media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid-framework.scss 32:5   make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 72:3                    @import
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 16:9                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 8:9                                    root stylesheet

DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
```

Could anyone help to resolve this please? Thank you

Comment: I do have below files included in the head section   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
   <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use version [1.33.0](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.33.0), use the version before that [1.32.13](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.32.13) for now.
Change it on your package.json `"sass": "1.32.13"`
And wait for the fix on the next version.

Comment: Which laravel version are you using @Jim.B

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You either have a syntax error in /resources/sass/app.scss. Open the file and search for  `flex: 0 0 100% / $count;` Replace with  `flex: 0 0 math.div(100%, $count)` If it's not there then your version of bootstrap have broken changes try updating</strike>

Version related see accepted answer

Reference https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

Comment: Yeah, have fun fixing all the lines in bootstrap with that solution.